# Need Powershell script to get all public IP addresses with attached resource name, Resource group, in all subcriptions

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

In our organization, there are about 4,000 subscriptions. So I need a powershell script to get all public IP addresses with attached resource name, in excel or csv format.

Used below scripts but its only showing IP address:

```
az login

$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) { az network public-ip list --subscription $sub.Name --query "[?ipAddress!=null]|[?contains(ipAddress, '$IP')].[ipAddress]" --output table }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Get all public IP addresses with attached resource name, Resource group, in all subscriptions:

*Use azure PowerShell command* `Get-AZPublicIpAddress`:

```
 Get-AzPublicIpAddress | Export-Csv -Path /home/pathxxxx/new.csv | format-table
```

***Get resourcegroup, resource as well as creation data etc fields as shown:***

[image]

*Set subscription using below script if needed for a specific subscription:*

```
$subsscriptions = Get-AzSubscription 
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    Write-Host "$subscription.Name"
$SelectSub = Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscription.Name
}
#Add code here as per the requirement#
```

***Exported output to excel sheet using*** `export-CSV` ***powershell command:***
[image]